# Magento2 use Multiple LIKE operator in Join Query

Tags: magento2, sql, join-table, join

I have used Join query,in which i'm able to fetch only one row by below query 
where `$productId = 10`

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('paproduct.product_id = (?)', $productId);
```

I want to use multiple `$productId` in array (May be with LIKE operator).
How can i do it?

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('paproduct.product_id LIKE ?', $productId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **IN** instead **LIKE**. For example:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('paproduct.product_id IN (?)', $productId);
```

**$productId** should be array. Like:

```
$productId = [1,2];
```

Comment: It's so simple, why I dont know this?